# JPQL Native Query using SUM and COUNT

Tags: java, sql, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I am trying to run the following code:

```
public BigDecimal valuate(String searchTerms, String categoryPath) {
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT SUM(maxBidAmount) / COUNT(maxBidAmount) FROM Item WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST(':searchTerms') AND categoryPath=':categoryPath'", Double.class);
    query.setParameter("searchTerms", searchTerms);
    query.setParameter("categoryPath", categoryPath);
    double value = (double) query.getSingleResult();
    return new BigDecimal(value);
}
```

When I do so, I get the following exception:

```
Exception Description: Missing descriptor for [class java.lang.Double].
```

When I remove `Double.class`, I get a different exception.

So, I'm just wondering the correct method of using COUNT and SUM with JPQL.

Comment: With hibernate 4 and Oracle driver and no explicitely specified type I get "Number" as the class, which can be used with Number#intValue(). Maybe you can try `Number.class` instead of `Double.class`?

    int value = ((Number)query.getSingleResult()).intValue();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IF the SQL is valid, you do not need to specify the Double.class in the query def - just use em.createNativeQuery(SQLString); 
The return type is used when you want the JPA provider to build an entity from the results, but in this case you want the raw data.

Comment: When I combined this advice with NOT using query parameters, and simply piecing together strings, the query worked, thanks.

Comment: In my case it returns BigInteger, I typically cast it to Number, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342572/retrieving-single-value-using-jpa/8342658

Answer (score 0):

Native query is *SQL*, not *JPQL*, and you use those keywords just like any SQL for your RDBMS.
Looks like your JPA provider doesn't accept Double as a result class (some only allow the result class to be an Entity).

DataNucleus JPA certainly allows non-Entity result classes.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is not JPQL. Double is a simple type, so I would have assumed that it would be supported. I have a feeling it is my errornous approach rather than a defficiency in the JPA implementation (Eclipse Link).

Comment: You should use numbered parameters ?1, ?2 etc instead of :param1 when using SQL via JPA. That doesn't fix the Double part, but as I already said ... some implementations would support that