# In which cases the return type is java.math.BigDecimal for a native query with "Select count(columnName) ..."

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I'm using a native query like this:

```
public Long count() {  
String sql = "SELECT COUNT(t.task_id_t100) from T100_TASK t ";  
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);  
return (Long) query.getSingleResult();  
}
```

This always worked. Today I got a `ClassCastException` because `query.getSingleResult()` returned a `BigDecimal`. I can't remember to have changed anything.

The hint in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342572/retrieving-single-value-using-jpa) tells `Note that in some cases result type may depend on the database, i.e. it can be something like BigDecimal`

In which cases?

Comment: Some RDBMS will return the equivalent of BigDecimal and some won't. That's one of the downsides of RDBMS vendors not implementing the same interpretation of 'standard SQL'. Did you change your RDBMS? Far safer to see what type it is on return and cast accordingly

Comment: I think that the best way is to return/cast it to a `Number`, and use the `longValue()` method.

Comment: Number.longValue() works fine. @NeilStockton no. The rdbms did not changed. Therefore the question. It is a strange behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply ask the object which class it is...

```
public Long count() {  
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(t.task_id_t100) from T100_TASK t ";  
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);  
    Object o = query.getSingleResult(); 
    //for BigDecimal
    if (o.getClass().equals(BigDecimal.class) ){
        BigDecimal big = (BigDecimal) o;
        return handleBigDecimal(big); //TODO
    }
    //other types might follow
    return (Long) o;  
}
```

but remember - a bigDecimal can be much bigger than a long can be... (can be.. not guaranteed)